# Stator rewind for 1929 motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'm trying to fix an old (1929?) AC, 60 Hz fan motor.  None of what I've found is this simple (or old). It needs the stator rewound. It has only 4 posts and I'm copying the orginal windings. I could not tell from the old winding if the poles alternate polarity. Physically, I'm winding them all clockwise but can alternate, if need be, by connecting adjacent coils head-to-head & tail-to-tail. Right hand rule would reverse the N-pole. I presume the 60 Hz house current provides the modulation to actually make the motor spin. I've attached a photo. [image: beginning the rewind porcess]

Comment: Be careful! Make sure that your windings don't spread out at the ends to the point where they interfere with your ability to later insert the rotor. That first one looks iffy.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to EE SE. There are votes to close your question, because it's about repairing. However, if you put more info about the research you've done into your question and broaden the focus in a way that goes more towards general motor design and less towards just one particular problem, this might become a really interesting Q&A. There's already a good answer attracting many upvotes. Please show your research effort and edit more info into the question... Much can be learned while repairing stuff, and I'd like your question very much not to be closed.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a pretty simplistic shaded-pole induction motor. Here's a schematic that's almost identical to your photo:
(second one from a Google search)
[image: winding diagram]

As shown in that diagram, you'll want to reverse the connections on you winding coils.